# Problems running AJAX within a file loaded previously via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I've been using this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  //stops it caching the values so form can be change and the result updated without need for refreshing the page
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#select_user').live('submit', function(e) {      
            e.preventDefault(); // stops form from submitting naturally
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                url: $(this).attr('action') ,  //gets the form url from the atribute 'action' on the form.
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#result').html(response); 
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Too produce an ajax request and pass variables from a form to another file, which is working fine. The file that is outputted into the div 'result' has another form and I want this to pass to another div inside the file that is loaded into 'result'.  I was hoping to just copy the code changing the different form names and divs it is outputted but this never worked.  Any ideas into how I may do this.

Tried to explain it best I could, I know its a little confusing!

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you're missing the closing `</script>` tag? (just some minor troubleshooting, may not solve your entire problem)

Comment: Are you saying that the html that you set on this line: `$('#result').html(response); ` contains javascript? If so, it won't work -- the "ready" event won't be triggered again for just that little chunk of js.

Comment: What happens is a user is selected which then loads the users page into the DIV result.  In the users page, which is a php file, there are sub pages that when selected, should display into a div on the users page. Hope this should clarify things. Thanks

Comment: @Chris: There won't be a triggered event, but everything passed to $.ready will be executed immidiately when the DOM *is* already ready.